# How can I use a different CSS using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, css, android

I was designing a mobile version of my website but then realized I need to support at least three (iPhone, iPad and Android). In that case, I was thinking of using jQuery for the task where I would first detect what device it is and then load the appropriate CSS. How would I go about doing this? Is it something like this? And is this even the good way or is there a better way of achieving the same?

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
   //Detect device type using jQuery
   //Insert the proper stylesheet?

   //Rest of the javascript
</script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind putting all you CSS into one stylesheet you could do this:

Place this in the `<head>` tag of your HTML:
`<link id="ss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="norm.css" />`

And then add this to your javascript file.

```
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (uagent.search("iphone") > -1)
{
    $("#ss").attr("herf", "iphone.css");
}
if (uagent.search("ipad") > -1)
{
    $("#ss").attr("herf", "ipad.css");
}
if (uagent.search("andriod") > -1)
{
    $("#ss").attr("herf", "android.css");
}
```